# Remote Service shuts down once program closes

Tags: c#, windows-services

We have a service that we created (and runs on one of our servers) which I'd like to control via another program.  I having some difficulty with the service though and hope someone can help.

If I try to control the service using the route below, it works only with users that are on the server as well:

```
ServiceController service = new ServiceController("MyService", "MyServer");

try
{
    if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        teServiceStatus.Text = "Running";
        sbStartService.Enabled = false;
        sbStopService.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.Red;
        teServiceStatus.Text = "Stopped";
        sbStartService.Enabled = true;
        sbStopService.Enabled = false;
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    else
    {
        teServiceStatus.Text = "Cannot Connect";
        teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    else
        ;
}
```

So as a Network User, I am also on the server as a user and when I run our program that wants to control this service, I can see the status and start and stop it, but no one else can (unless I add them to the Server, which I don't wish to do).

I can also use the route below and impersonate a user on the Server:

```
//Establish connection to the Publishing Server with application credentials.
ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
connectionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
connectionOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
connectionOptions.Username = "UserOnServer";
connectionOptions.Password = "UserPassword";
ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\MyServer\root\cimv2", connectionOptions);
managementScope.Connect();

ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath("Win32_Service");
ManagementClass services = new ManagementClass(managementScope, path, null);

foreach (ManagementObject service in services.GetInstances())
{
    try
    {
        if (service.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() == "MyService")
            if (service.GetPropertyValue("State").ToString().ToLower().Equals("running"))
            {
                teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                teServiceStatus.Text = "Running";
                sbStartService.Enabled = false;
                sbStopService.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.Red;
                teServiceStatus.Text = "Stopped";
                sbStartService.Enabled = true;
                sbStopService.Enabled = false;
            }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        else
        {
            teServiceStatus.Text = "Cannot Connect";
            teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        else
        {
            teServiceStatus.Text = "Cannot Connect";
            teServiceStatus.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

This works so that any user who uses the program can start/stop the service and see it's current status BUT, when the program closes, the Service stops (don't know if that's supposed to happen, but it is).

So how can I have my program start, stop, and read a service status by anyone who uses it?  I feel I am close but apparently, missing something.

**UPDATE**
When using the ConnectionOptions route, it seems as soon as the form in which the ConnectionOptions (or ManagementScope) is in, closes, then the server records it as the logged in user has "Logged Off", and shuts down the service at that time.  I don't know why, but still trying to look into it.

Comment: Is there anything being written to the event log on the machine the service is running on?  There might be an unhandled exception to blame here.

Comment: I don't show anything unusual...it shows that the Service has started, but nothing when it stops (by closing the program).

Comment: I see there is an error in the System log: "The MyService service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 60000 milliseconds: Restart the service."  but I don't see any specific reason as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your running client code impersonate the `NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService` account so that it has the same level of permissions as your service. [The password is null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755249.aspx) (or maybe empty string, try both I guess) for that account. The documentation on how to run code while impersonating that user is demonstrated in [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx). More info here on [Impersonation/Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949004.aspx).

Also, you may want to implement [handlers for all unhandled exceptions](http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/) in your service. It's possible that exceptions are being thrown outside of your try/catch blocks, and that's why your application is exiting without your attached debugger breaking on any breakpoints set in your catch blocks.